# How to transfer data securly via bluetooth classic using TLS

Tags: android, sockets, network-programming, tls1.2, bluetooth-socket

I'm a developing mobile application (using Android) in which I want to transfer data to the other application (Desktop) via Bluetooth.

I can enable search, pair and establish connection between the Bluetooth devices and able to send data.

But I wanted to send the data securely by implementing TLS at application layer level. I searched for answers but could not find for transferring data via Bluetooth.

I even came across this post: [Using TLS in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38422947/using-tls-in-android)

I came across spongy castle to implement TLS but I could not get the sample for Bluetooth.

Is it possible to implement TLS for Bluetooth? If yes can someone please guide and share the samples or tutorials.

Thanks.